# Using Blender for a 2D design for cnc plasma cutter

Tags: mesh, image

Blender 2.78a. I want to design a 2 dimensional object to be cut on a CNC Plasma cutter that utilizes DXF format. If I use Blenders; Nurbs Circle, Nurbs Surface tools only, will that be suffice for the Plasma Cutter with DXF?

Comment: Use a proper CAD too for this, Blender is not well suited for 2D, CAD, or CAM work. Mesh modeling is not a good format for computer aided manufacturing processes, NURBS and vector tools are much better, both of which are particularly crude under Blender. Try Something like [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/), [LibreCAD](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html) or perhaps [DraftSight](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/)

Comment: If you really are heart set on using Blender in this way, you can implement it yourself, but you will have to write out raw DXF to a file using python. [Here's an online reference to the DXF Reference of R14 - which most plasmas should be able to read, even the old ones](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/dxf/reference/). I'm really with Duarte on this one, this is no small undertaking.

Comment: I am new to 3D and to this site. I appreciate both your responses. I agree with you Rick about Duarte's advice and will take it. I found that I am a nervous wreck worrying about whether or not I ask the correct question, answer the question correctly etc. over the last 24 hours (laughing at myself right now). I need to have more in-depth discussions and questions. I don't want to bother anyone, so I'll jump over to another site (Blenderartists) to satisfy my curious needs. Thank you all for your help and support. D.J.